# The results array skimage method color.rgb2gray are sometimes not normalized

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

I was trying the color.rgb2gray function of skimge. The result array should be normalized according to the function description.

But I found the max value is not 1 in some cases

For example:

```
[In]:color.rgb2gray(data.chelsea()).max()
[out]:0.7556109803921569
[In]:color.rgb2gray(data.coins()).max()
[out]:252
```

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the docstring saying anything about normalization.  But, the issue you are running into is that skimage understands both images represented with `dtype == np.uint8` and `dtype == float`.  The latter images are in [0, 1], the prior in [0, 255].  So, you'll see:

```
In [7]: color.rgb2gray(data.chelsea()).max()
Out[7]: 0.75561098039215691

In [8]: color.rgb2gray(data.chelsea()).dtype
Out[8]: dtype('float64')

In [9]: color.rgb2gray(data.coins()).max()
Out[9]: 252

In [10]: color.rgb2gray(data.coins()).dtype
Out[10]: dtype('uint8')
```

See also http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.14.x/user_guide/data_types.html